# How to validate mysql database URI

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm trying to integrate a Gem named blazer with my Rails application and I have to specify mysql database URL in blazer.yml file so that it can access data in staging and production environments.

I believe the standard format to define MySQL database URL is

```
mysql2://user:password@hostname:3306/database
```

I defined my URL in the same format as a string and when I validate the URI I get the below error

> URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):
>   mysql2://f77_oe_85_staging:LcCh%264855c6M;kG9yGhjghjZC?JquGVK@factory97-aurora-staging-cluster.cluster-cmj77682fpy4kjl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/factory97_oe85_staging

Defined Mysql database URL:

```
'mysql2://f77_oe_85_staging:LcCh%264855c6M;kG9yGhjghjZC?JquGVK@factory97-aurora-staging-cluster.cluster-cmj77682fpy4kjl.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/factory97_oe85_staging'
```

Please advice

Comment: Have you tried `mysql:...` instead of `mysql2:...`?

Comment: I did try mysql: too.. It throws same error -   URI::InvalidURIError - the scheme mysql does not accept registry part:     @MasaSakano

Comment: I see. Have you tried `URI.encode()`? The raw character '%' should not be in a URI. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494773/rails-not-parsing-database-url-on-production/44495671#44495671) "Rails not parsing database URL on production"

Comment: Yes. I tried URI.encode() and no luck with that either. I think I should reset the staging password to not have any special characters in it. @MasaSakano

Comment: If it works after changing the password to the one without special characters, then it means your escaping algorithm was incorrect. I have posted an answer as a strategy of how to tackle it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URI is invalid.

The problem is the password contains characters which are not valid in a URI. The `username:password` is the `userinfo` part of a URI. From [RFC 3986](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#authority)...

```
  foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
   |           |            |            |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment

authority   = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )

pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
            / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Specifically it's the `?` in the password `LcCh%264855c6M;kG9yGhjghjZC?JquGVK`. It looks like the password is only partially escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I think a problem is the issue is not well isolated.  Here is an *example* strategy of how to isolate it.

The error code of `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):` only indicates the library (blazer gem) successfully read a file, which may or may not be the file you have edited, `/YOUR_DIR/blazer.yml` or something, but nevertheless failed to parse the URI.

Now, the issues to consider include:

1. blazer gem really read `/YOUR_DIR/blazer.yml`?
2. does the preprocessor of the yml work as expected?
3. is the **uri** key specified correct?
4. `mysql:` or `mysql2`?
5. are the formats of IP, port, account name, password, and database name all correct?  In particular, are special characters correctly escaped? (See [MySql document about special characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html))

I suppose the OP knows answers of some of these questions but we don't. So, let's assume any of them can be an issue.

Then a proposed strategy is this:

1. Find a URI that is at least in a correct format and confirm it is parsed and recognised correctly by Gem blazer.  Note you only need to test the format and so dummy parameters are fine.  For example, try a combination of the following and see which does not issue the error `URI::InvalidURIError`:

   1. `mysql://127.0.0.1/test`
   2. `mysql://adam:alphabetonly@127.0.0.1/test`
   3. `jdbc:mysql://adam:alphabetonly@127.0.0.1/test`

   Now, you know at least the potential issues (1),(3),(4) are irrelevant.
2. Replace the IP (hostname), account name, password, and database name one by one with the real one and find which raises the error `URI::InvalidURIError`.  Now you have narrowed down which part causes a problem.  In the OP's case, I suspect the problem is an incorrect escape of the special characters in the password part.  Let's assume that is the case, and then,
3. properly escape the part so that they form a correct URI format as a whole. The answer by @Schwern is a good summary about the format.  As a tip, you can get an escape URI by opening Rail's console (via `rails c`) and typing `URI.encode('YOUR_PASSWORD')` or alternatively, run ruby directly from the command-line in a (UNIX-shell) terminal:

   ```
   ruby -ruri -e "puts URI.encode('YOUR_PASSWORD')"
   ```

   Replace the password part in the URI in `/YOUR_DIR/blazer.yml` with the escaped string, and confirm it does not issue the error `URI::InvalidURIError` (hopefully).

In these processing, I deliberately avoided the preprocessor part, (2).
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494773/rails-not-parsing-database-url-on-production/44495671#44495671) to "Rails not parsing database URL on production" mentions about `URI.encode('YOUR_PASSWORD')` in a yml file, but it implicitly assumes a preprocessor works fine. During the test phase, that just adds another layer of complication, and so it is better to skip it.  If you need it in your production (to mask the password etc), implement it later, when you know everything else works fine.

Hope by the time the OP has tried all of these, the problem is solved.

Comment: I've tried all the cases you have mentioned in your answer. I tried by getting rid of special characters in my password and it threw a different error saying 'Access denied for username@password'. That means the issue I mentioned in the post occurred due to special characters in the password. I used URI.encode method and still it didn't serve the purpose as I got an error saying "Undefined method split for gsub method".   I updated the password of the MySQL user without having any special characters and updated the same in the database.yml file and blazer.yml file and that worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Masa Sakano for your time and help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need to write `URI.encode` in any of your files. You run it completely independently of your app (or actually you even don't need it but instead just use a free web service to encode the string). The error you encountered seems strange… I have no idea. Anyway I'm glad to hear you've found a solution. If you find what went wrong one day, you can come back here and leave a comment.